# Jest global variables dynamically imported from a JS file (export.module)

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

I need to import a .js file with config values to be used on my react app:

> `import config from './config'`

These values are already added at **webpack** configuration:

> **new** webpack.DefinePlugin({...config})

What I need is to import these values into `jest.config.js`:

```
globals: {
  config: // Here config...
}
```

"I know that we can add these values manually, but I want to add them from this file to prevent the maintenance of all values instead".

Thanks!

Comment: why cant you import them and add to global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object
>
> Note that, if you specify a global reference value (like an object or array) here, and some code mutates that value in the midst of running a test, that mutation will not be persisted across test runs for other test files. In addition the globals object must be json-serializable, so it can't be used to specify global functions.

here is a guide on adding globals to your jest config with basic usage below

```
 import * as config from "path/to/config";    

 //...package.json || jest.config
 "jest": {
   "globals": {
     ...config
   }
 }
```

```js
const config = {
  this: 'is now global'
}


console.log({
  jest: {
    globals: {
      ...config
    }
  }
})
```

You can add it to the globals object and import the config as normal

Comment: Thanks Joe, I already found the solution myself at this documentation. It just was because I didn't read this point. But I'll accept your answer and I wont delete this solution after all ;)

Comment: @IvanSanchez Could you also  help to provide the answer or a link to the documentation